# How does Magecraft work for (Human Mark of Making)?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, eberron

In regards to Magecraft can someone help define how long "temporary magic item" last. Also, How many of these Items you can have at one time.

for example a pair of wrist wraps that will allow me to cast Toll of the Dead first turn/action, and on second turn/action/reaction,bonus action cast Firebolt.

In WGE **Magecraft**. *You can create a temporary magic item out of common materials. Choose a cantrip from the wizard spell list. Describe the item connected to it. As long as you possess the item, you know that cantrip. At the end of a long rest, you can replace it with a new item and select a new cantrip from the wizard spell list. Intelligence is your spellcasting ability for these cantrips.*

Comment: Are you intending to cast *firebolt* as a bonus action or reaction because of the magic item, or do you have different feature that would allow it? The casting time for *firebolt* is one action.

Comment: wasn't certain, but i suspect it will take two separate turns. I was asking because different cantrips can be beneficial at different times, so having a stock of them  pre-built would be helpful. Since Mark of making makes them.

Comment: Related answer to a different question on using action cantrips with different types of activity: [Can a Reaction Cantrip be used as an action and bonus action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/138635/41726)

Comment: Could you please put the question itself in the title?

Comment: Where do you get the idea that you can change spells between rounds?

Comment: I not certain, that is why i am asking can i have more than one item made?

Answer (score 8):

In this case, temporary means "until you choose to change it according to the stated rules", and you get one and only one at a time.

When you acquire Magecraft (at character generation), you make one item with one cantrip in it. You can replace the item (and the contained cantrip) at the end of a long rest, as it says. It doesn't give any rules for creating a new item except by losing your previous one. So you can only have one at a time, but every morning you can enchant a new temporary item to switch to a new wizard cantrip at the cost of losing the old one.

Based on your comments, I think you might be confused about how this ability operates. The item you make contains one cantrip, but not one *casting of* that cantrip. While you have the item, you can use that cantrip every single round if you want to. It isn't a scroll that goes away after it's used.

So, you can't create wrist wraps that let you cast both *toll the dead* and *fire bolt*; you'd have to pick one or the other every morning (or any other wizard cantrip), but once you do, you can shoot that one spell all day long.

I'm not sure why you brought up bonus actions and reactions -- spells take whatever kind of action they say they take, so you can't ever use *fire bolt* as a reaction or bonus action unless you have an ability that explicitly allows you to do so, such as a sorcerer burning sorcery points to Quicken a spell.

However, you're correct in identifying that this particular piece of rules text is not quite right. Normally I'd expect to see it either say "You create an item" (meaning immediately upon gaining the ability) or "You can create an item" followed by specific rules about when and how you initially create the item (whether for the first time or if the previous one is lost/destroyed), and then in either case specify how and when you can change the item (as it already does).

Since the WGE rules will be superseded in a month or so here when the *Eberron: Rising From the Last War* book comes out, I expect (assuming the Mark of Making comes through largely unchanged) that this particular text will be slightly altered to make it more clear how it operates.

Comment: Pertinent: the OP seems to believe that he can enchant his wrist wraps to cast a cantrip as a bonus action/reaction/etc.  That seems like somethign that shoudl be cleared up.

Comment: @BenBarden I added some comments on that front.